# Two tab controllers in app

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to implement this hierarchy in app. I know that maybe its not a good UI solution. But I have designs for an app and I want to implement it.

I want to approach like this:

[image]

But I always see FirstTabBarController in ViewControllers which have embeded in SecondTabBarController.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below approach:

1) On window root controller assign UINavigationController (call it App Navigation Controller)

2) Push and Pop your custom UITabbarControllers to the App Navigation Controller as per your app requirement

3) Handle flow of your custom child controllers of your custom  tabar controllers from there only.

Comment: But I have a question. If I need that, one FirstBarController will be as main TabBarController. And If I go to another controller then showing SecondBarController. How to do it?

Comment: You can push the SecondBarController in App Navigation Controller

Comment: Or maybe it's possible to display another TabBarItem in different controllers?

Comment: When you want to show the SecondBarController then you only need to push the SecondBarController instance in your App Navigation Controller instance